# Difference between / and /**

Tags: url, spring-mvc

I am confused between the URL pattern `/` and `/**` w.r.t `AntPAthMatcher`.

I know `/**` is a universal pattern that will match all the URLs, but I am not sure what does `/` will match.

I have tried searching the difference, but no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/**` will match any number of (0 or more) levels in a path, eg. it would match both `/file` and `/some/path/file`.

A single asterisk `/*` only matches 0 or more *characters* (not path levels) so it would match `/file` but *not* `/some/path/file`.

A single slash `/` would only match the root path.

Comment: Thanks, One more doubt in web.xml when we specify servlet url mapping for e.g for spring mvc dispatcher servlet we use <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> and not <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern> for passing all requests to dispatcher servlet, it works differently then AntPathMatcher ?

Comment: Yes very differently... `/*` in web.xml will match all paths. `AntPathMatcher` is based on Apache Ant's path patterns.